# How do I create a command to be used in these ViewModels added to a View?

Tags: c#, wpf

In the following related question, I asked about creating custom items to be used on a View:

[Can I make this block of XAML into a reusable "control"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682000/can-i-make-this-block-of-xaml-into-a-reusable-control/43682407?noredirect=1#comment74411162_43682407)

That worked great, and I now have the items displayed as I wanted.  However, there is no `Command` property or `Click` event for me to use for capturing a mouse click on the item.  I would like my ViewModel to be able to react to the click.

Nothing I've tried has been able to expose the Command/Event (etc) in the XAML.  I go to the object's code, but nothing shows up for use there:

```
<vm:BackstageClickableItemViewModel x:Name="btnApplicationLog" FileName="Application Log" ImageSource="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=Windows_16x16.png}" />
```

Basically, I get the properties exposed by the ViewModel and that's all.  How can I get something I can attach a behavior to?

Answer (score 1):

insert your command in the XAML of your custom user control, in your `ViewModelBase` you create your command

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public virtual ICommand MyCommand => new RelayCommand(MyClick);

    protected virtual void MyClick(object o)
    {
        //Nothing here, just exists to be overriden
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is override your command in your views

```
public class MyViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    protected override void MyClick(object o)
    {
        //Your click logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the XAML:

```
  <vm:BackstageClickableItemViewModel x:Name="btnApplicationLog" FileName="Application Log" ImageSource="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=Windows_16x16.png}" >
    <vm:BackstageClickableItemViewModel.InputBindings>
      <MouseBinding Command="{Binding myCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
    </vm:BackstageClickableItemViewModel.InputBindings>
  </vm:BackstageClickableItemViewModel>
```

where `myCommand` is an `ICommand` object in your ViewModel.

This essentially binds you command to the mouse left-click on the entire usercontrol.

Comment: Interesting, but intellisense claims that `InputBindings` is not a valid bit of syntax:  "The member InputBindings is not recognized or is not accessible".

Comment: It works for me when binding to a custom control that inherits from `UserControl`.  If that's not the case here, I can see where it might not be the same.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  The ViewModel is exactly what is shown in the linked answer.